# If $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for all $x,y\ge 0$, then what is the form of $f(\cdot)$?

Tags: functions

If $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for all $x,y\ge 0$ and some functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$, then can we say something about the form of $f(\cdot)$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a precise definition of "form of a function".  Loosely, the "form" of $f$ is $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$

In descriptive language, we'd say "$f$ is [multiplicatively] separable", so perhaps you mean that.

Comment: Thanks. I think this answers my question. What I meant by "form" is something like $x^a$. Now it seems that $x^a$ is a common example for multiplicatively separable functions, but there are special functions that also satisfy this property.

Answer (score 0):

What you are speaking about in comment is the functional equation as functional characteristics of function: exists unique non trivial, continuous function  with property $f(x \cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ and it is $f(x)=x^\mu$, for some $\mu$. One possible generalization can be [Homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism).

Main difference between brought and your case is that you have function for $2$ variables. In hope it will be helpful let me, at end,  remind well known theorem for independent random variables:

If X and Y are absolutely continuous, then X and Y are independent iff the joint
density is equal to the product of the marginal ones, that is iff
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$$